# Symfony: OneToMany Bidirectionnal Relation

Tags: symfony, one-to-many

This is my entity "Product" :

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /*
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShopBundle\Entity\Offer", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $offers;

    /*
     * Constructeur
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->offers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add offer
     * @param \ShopBundle\Entity\Offer $offer
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addOffer(\ShopBundle\Entity\Offer $offer)
    {
        $this->offers[] = $offer;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove offer
     * @param \ShopBundle\Entity\Offer $offer
     */
    public function removeOffer(\ShopBundle\Entity\Offer $offer)
    {
        $this->offers->removeElement($offer);
    }

    /**
     * Get parameters
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getOffers()
    {
        return $this->offers;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

And, this is my entity "Offer" :

```
class Offer
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ShopBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="offers", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param \ShopBundle\Entity\Product $product
     *
     * @return Offer
     */
    public function setProduct(\ShopBundle\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \ShopBundle\Entity\Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

When, I get an object in my controller with 
$product = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Product')->find($id);

Then, $product->getOffers() return null but in database there isn't null.

Help me ... please ...

Comment: What result return $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Offer')->findByProduct($product) ?

Comment: it return good elements "offers" of "product"

Comment: did you try to clear Symfony cache? or do the cache warmup? run also `app/console doctrine:mapping:info` to see if mapping is OK and maybe clear doctrine cache  `app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`, 
 `app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query`,
 `app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result`

Comment: I'm doing everything. Identical results ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Product` entity, you are missing the second `*` character that introduces the docblock which contains mapping information for `$offers`:

```
/*
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShopBundle\Entity\Offer", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $offers;
```

Thefore, PHP treats these lines as normal comments and not as docblocks which means that Doctrine doesn't know anything about them.

Just change it to something like this:

```
class Product
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShopBundle\Entity\Offer", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $offers;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much xabbuh ... 
just for a star ... rrrrrrr